TIKZUML ERROR : in umlobject, invalid option width
I'm trying to compile this sequence diagram but I'm getting these errors:
TIKZUML ERROR : in umlobject, invalid option width.
Extra \or.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
    \umlactor[width=2cm]{Utilisateur}
    \umlobject[width=3cm]{Plateforme}
    \umldatabase[width=3cm]{BaseDeDonnees}
    
    \begin{umlcall}[op=Entrer identifiants(), type=synchron]{Utilisateur}{Plateforme}
        \begin{umlcall}[op=Vérifier identifiants(), type=synchron]{Plateforme}{BaseDeDonnees}
            \begin{umlfragment}[type=alt, label=Validité des identifiants]
                \begin{umlfragment}[type=condition, label=Valides]
                    \begin{umlcall}[op=Récupérer infos utilisateur(), type=asynchron]{BaseDeDonnees}{Plateforme}
                    \end{umlcall}
                    \begin{umlcallself}[op=Générer token(), type=synchron]{Plateforme}
                    \end{umlcallself}
                    \begin{umlcall}[op=Envoyer token(), type=synchron]{Plateforme}{Utilisateur}
                    \end{umlcall}
                \end{umlfragment}
                \umlfpart[default, label=Invalides]
                \begin{umlcall}[op=Afficher message d'erreur(), type=synchron]{Plateforme}{Utilisateur}
                \end{umlcall}
            \end{umlfragment}
        \end{umlcall}
    \end{umlcall}
    
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

However I added this to my file tikz-uml.sty :
\newenvironment{umlcallKill}[3][]
{
    \stepcounter{tikzumlCallNum}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@lastchildNum{\thetikzumlCallNum}
    \gdef\tikzumlCallBottom{0}
    \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/call/.cd, 
            dt/.initial=\tikzumlCallDefaultDT, 
            name/.initial={call-\thetikzumlCallNum},
                        op/.initial={},
                        .unknown/.code=
                        {
                            \let\keyname=\pgfkeyscurrentname
                                \let\keyvalue=\pgfkeyscurrentvalue
                                \errmessage{TIKZUML ERROR : in umlcallKill,  invalid option \keyname}
                        }
    }
    \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/call/.cd, #1}
    \pgfkeys{/tikzuml/call/.cd, dt/.get=\tikzumlCallDT, op/.get=\tikzumlCallOp}
  
    \let\tikzumlCallStartNodeNameold\tikzumlCallStartNodeName
    \def\tikzumlCallStartNodeName{#2}
    \let\tikzumlCallEndNodeNameold\tikzumlCallEndNodeName
    \def\tikzumlCallEndNodeName{#3}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@parent{}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@parentold{}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@nameold{}
    \edef\tikzumlCall@name{call-\thetikzumlCallNum}

    \begingroup
    \def\_{_}\edef\x{\endgroup
        \def\noexpand\tikzumlCall@nodeName{\tikzumlCall@name}}\x
    \let\tikzumlCall@nodeNameold\tikzumlCall@nodeName
    % top node of activity period of call sender
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{connections}
        \pgfmathparse{\tikzumlCallDT}
        \draw (\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallStartNodeName \endcsname)+(0,-\pgfmathresult ex) node[coordinate, name=tikzumlTmpNode] {};
        \node[tikzuml activity style] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallStartNodeName |- tikzumlTmpNode) {};
        % update last node drawn on sender lifeline
        \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallStartNodeName \endcsname{st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
        \node[tikzuml activity style, draw=none] (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallEndNodeName |- st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) {};
        % update last node drawn on receiver lifeline
        \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallEndNodeName \endcsname{et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
        \xdef\tikzumlCallBottomSrc{et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}%
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \stepcounter{tikzumlCallLevel}
}{
    \addtocounter{tikzumlCallLevel}{-1}
    % bottom nodes of activity periods of call sender and receiver
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{connections}
            \draw (\tikzumlCallBottomSrc)+(0, -0.2 ex) node[coordinate, name=tikzumlTmpNode] {};
            \node[cross out, draw=black, line width=1pt, minimum size=12pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallEndNodeName |- tikzumlTmpNode) {};
            \node[tikzuml activity style] (sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) at (\tikzumlCallStartNodeName |- eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName) {};
            \xdef\tikzumlCallBottomSrc{sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % draw activity periods
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{activity}
            % draw root activity period
            \draw[draw=\tikzumlDefaultDrawColor, fill=\tikzumlCallDefaultFillColor] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.north west) rectangle (sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.south east);
            % Do not draw receiver activity period
            \draw[draw=none] (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.north west) rectangle (eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.south east);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    % update last nodes drawn on sender and receiver lifelines
    \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallEndNodeName \endcsname{eb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
    \expandafter\xdef\csname tikzumlLastChild@\tikzumlCallStartNodeName \endcsname{sb-\tikzumlCall@nodeName}
    % draw call arrows
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{connections}
            \pgfextractx{\tikzumlCall@xa}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzumlCallStartNodeName}{center}}
            \pgfextractx{\tikzumlCall@xb}{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzumlCallEndNodeName}{center}}
            \ifthenelse{\tikzumlCall@xb>\tikzumlCall@xa}
            {
                \draw[tikzuml synchron-msg style, \tikzumlDefaultDrawColor] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.east) -- (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.west) 
                node[font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, text=\tikzumlDefaultTextColor, midway, above=-0.4ex, name=\tikzumlCall@nodeName-op] {\tikzumlCallOp};
            }
            {
                \draw[tikzuml synchron-msg style, \tikzumlDefaultDrawColor] (st-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.west) -- (et-\tikzumlCall@nodeName.east) 
                node[font=\tikzumlDefaultFont, text=\tikzumlDefaultTextColor, midway, above=-0.4ex, name=\tikzumlCall@nodeName-op] {\tikzumlCallOp};
            }
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}


what do you mean by "you added something to tikz-uml.sty"? You shouldn't change such a sty.

The \newenvironment{umlcallKill}[3][]
